# Github Page Blank, not using Jekyll or create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I have a React App that I'm trying to publish using github pages but the page is blank. I've renamed the repository to my username.github.io, I'm on the master branch and the index.html file is in the root directory. The only answers I've found for this were for Apps built with Jekyll or create-react-app.

link to the repository- https://github.com/davez01d/davez01d.github.io
link to the page- https://davez01d.github.io/

Comment: You will need to add a build configuration  to the webpack config.

Comment: Out of scope of the question, but you don't need to push node_modules to git.